# Silver electrorefining

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

Ok, so let's say I have raw silver which is polluted with a bit of gold, copper and lead.
So through electrorefining I want to make pure silver out of it.

Let's say I have it all in an acidic solution. What happens when I turn on the Voltage?
How would I prevent the other elements from getting electrolyzed?
Because when I have the electrorefining of copper it gets clean even when polluted with silver, so why doesn't the copper get electrolyzed as well?

Answer (score 1):

It depeds on the acid. If it is HCl then you will get [Wohlwill Process](http://info.goldavenue.com/info_site/in_glos/in_glos_wolhill.html) only the silver will be not disolved. So baisiclly what you want.